# Add values in a column if value in another column is true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Column1 Paid    Amount
A       Yes     $45
B       No      $15
C       Yes     $30
D       Yes     $60
E       No      $30
F       No      $25
```

What I want to do is add up all the values in column 3 as long as there corresponding value in the "Paid" column is "Yes".

Essentially so that I have total amount for how much I have currently been paid. So the example should have an effective output a value of $135.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"Yes",C:C)
```

Comment: Thanks! The formula I ended up using was was `=SUMIF('T-Shirt Orders'!E:E,"Yes",'T-Shirt Orders'!F:F)`